# Overlay YouTubePlayerFragment on List view

Tags: java, android, youtube-api

I wish to overlay YouTubePlayerFragment on my custom listView of video but I am getting the error [App unfortunately stops]..
This is my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="20dip">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/userId"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:imeOptions="actionGo"
    android:inputType="text" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/searchButton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="getUserYouTubeFeed"
    android:text="Click to Search" />

<com.gagan.ui.widget.VideosListView
    android:id="@+id/videosListView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />


 <com.gagan.ui.widget.VideosListView
 android:id="@+id/videosListViewHistory"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" />


 <com.gagan.ui.widget.VideosListView
 android:id="@+id/videosListViewFavourite"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" />


  <fragment
  android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment"
  android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </FrameLayout  >
```

Activity code:

```
 youTubePlayerFragment.getView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 fm.beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in,R.anim.fade_out);
 fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.videosListView,youTubePlayerFragment,"yt_id1");     
        fm.beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null);
        fm.beginTransaction().commit();
        player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(playerStateChangeListener);
        this.playerInstance = player;
        //player.cueVideo(videoID);
        player.loadVideo(videoID);
```

I am interested in:

1) Any corrections?
1) Am I missing anything?
2) Any better design or alternatives?

Thanks & Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the Solution...Changed the layout to RelativeLayout and onCreate method hide the fragment:

```
youTubePlayerFragment.getView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

& on OnItemClickListener just instantiate the player with parameters and show the youtubefragment:

```
youTubePlayerFragment.getView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

RelativeLayout  would stack[overlay] over the listView..

Thanks!